# Replacing div nodes when clicking a button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 windowDiv on my page that have a button with id `"#button"`. The button's purpose is to change the size of the windowDiv. The windowDiv has a large version (called `windowDiv`) and a small version (`windowDivSmall`).

The top container div of the page is called `topContainerDiv`.

The problem is that I can't get this to work for just one windowDiv, let alone all 5 of them. I know I need to use `topContainer.replaceChild(windowDiv, windowDivSmall);` but I just can't get it to work.

What I currently have is the following:

```
 $("#button").click(function() {
        $(topContainerDiv).replaceChild(this.windowDivSmall, this.windowDiv);
 // The code above is broken and doesn't work. Help!

    });
```

Comment: it would be great if you can share the code,otherwise this is hard to understand

Comment: `$(topContainerDiv)` is a jQuery object while I think `replaceChild` is a pure JS method of an HTML element object. So you should try `$(topContainerDiv)[0].replaceChild`... I'm not sure about that because I'm not good at jQuery.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code, but it looks like you're reusing the `button` id attribute five times. Id attributes must be unique within a document.

Comment: #button can be used only once , change ids for class and test again you code (update html and jquery for class instead id

Comment: I cannot see where windowDivSmall and windowDiv are defined.
Seems like that's probably the issue. since this <- is the button it seems like you're trying to do something strange :).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you to use 5 `#button`.

You cannot.
change in HTML `id="button"` for `class="button"` and update your jquery :

```
$(".button").click(function() {
       // correct jquery functions to call here :)
    });
```

Comment: Have you read [King King's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367543/replacing-div-nodes-when-clicking-a-button-in-javascript#comment35791864_23367543)?

Comment: yes , after i posted . he has then more than 1 error

Comment: Looks so. At least three, maybe more.

Comment: @GCyrillus What would be the correct jQuery function to call? Could you give an example please?

Comment: @Gregg1989 Can you provide you HTML in a fiddle or a codepen with some 'lorem ipsum' text , to have the picture of your structure. Add it to your question to make it clear for everyone passing by

Answer (score 0):

`replaceChild` is a JavaScript function. You are calling this function on a jQuery object. You could try the jQuery `replaceWith` method`: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/